# How to update a SQL Server table that has a column defined as TEXT with UPDATETEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update a SQL Server  table that has a column defined as TEXT with UPDATETEXT

I have tried

```
UPDATETEXT db.tablename 
SET ColumnName = ColumnName (‘data’)
WHERE UserID = ‘myID’
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

It works fine if I use NVARCHAR

```
UPDATE
SET...
WHERE..
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Stop wasting your time on trying to get this to work - switch to the new, a lot more useful datatypes and all your issues regarding updating will be gone!

Comment: The syntax for `UPDATETEXT` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/updatetext-transact-sql); it's not at all like `UPDATE`. Even if you have to use `TEXT` (when you should indeed by using `[N]VARCHAR(MAX)`), it's not likely you actually *need* `UPDATETEXT`. `UPDATE ... SET column = value` will work even if `column` is of type `TEXT`. `UPDATETEXT` is really only necessary if you 1) are stuck with `TEXT` and 2) have to update a huge value somewhere in the middle.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support "Smart" quotes (`‘’`) either, just "plain (ol')" single quotes (`'`) work for literal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/updatetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is all off. A correct usage of `UPDATETEXT` would look like this

```sql
DECLARE @ptrval BINARY(16);  
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(t.ColumnName) 
FROM tablename t
WHERE UserID = 'myID';

IF @ptrval IS NOT NULL
    UPDATETEXT tablename.ColumnName @ptrval 0 NULL 'data';
```

However, you don't actually need it at all, as you are replacing the whole value. It's only really useful if you want to do a partial update on a big value. You might as well do a normal update.

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET ColumnName = 'data'
WHERE UserID = 'myID';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e97622e77a9b5c5f2b0fbc5d4cce290)

---

Ideally, you wouldn't use `text` or `ntext` at all, as it's deprecated.

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN ColumnName varchar(max);
```

Then you can still do that `UPDATE`, or if you want a partial update you can use `.WRITE`

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET ColumnName.WRITE('data', 0, NULL)
WHERE UserID = 'myID';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=111e71abb48cc1b7bb60d0db57d8e00f)